# React Native: npm link local dependency, unable to resolve module

Tags: react-native, npm, npm-link

I am developing a button ui package for react native. I try to build an example project to test this button. The directory structure is as follows:

```
my-button/
    package.json
    index.js
    example/
        package.json
        index.js
```

I try to use `npm link`:

```
cd my-button
npm link

cd example
npm link my-button
```

In `example/node_modules/` I can see my-button symlink, VSCode also can auto complete function in my-button package.

But execute example app will show error:

```
Unable to resolve module my-button ...
Module does not exist in the module map or in these directories: ...
```

But the path in the error message is correct.

Don't know where I was wrong, or in React-Native have any special way to deal with link local dependency?

I also tried `npm install file:../.`. It works fine in this way, but not easy to update dependency in `example/` after I edited my-button.

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution to this or does React Native not support local npm packages?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

The `npm link` command doesn't work because React Native packager [doesn't support symlinks](https://github.com/facebook/metro-bundler/issues/1).

After a little research, I discovered that there are two ways to go about it.

1. Use [haul packager](https://github.com/callstack/haul) in the example app. Haul supports symlinks, so you can use `npm link` as usual.
2. Use local dependency via `file:../` and then edit files in `node_modules` folder or reinstall every time you make changes.

I found [Haul](https://github.com/callstack/haul) to work great for this use-case and even set-up a [little starter project](https://github.com/pavloko/react-native-library-starter) that also includes [storybook](https://github.com/storybooks/storybook), which is really helpful if you have many components to switch between.

Comment: I've just tested haul with an existing project and it is not working, seems unmainained

Comment: Haul has evolved into https://github.com/callstack/repack

Comment: The second option didn't work for me :(

Answer (score 55):

Try **wml** (https://github.com/wix/wml)

It's an alternative to `npm link` that actually copies changed files from source to destination folders

```
# add the link to wml using `wml add <src> <dest>`
wml add ~/my-package ~/main-project/node_modules/my-package

# start watching all links added
wml start
```

Comment: Be sure to shutdown your existing Metro Bundler packager instance and let React Native startup a new instance upon your next `react-native run-*****` command. Otherwise, you'll keep getting the error that the OP described.

Comment: Is wml still maintained? The repository does not have any contributions since 2017.

Comment: In case anyone is using this solution, and have problems with `node_modules` being linked too, before starting with `wml start` make sure to remove "node_modules" from the ignore list in `.watchmanconfig` file that is created by `wml`

Comment: @pmiranda were you able to make this work? I think the answer is outdated now.

Comment: WML worked for me in 2022, However had initial issue with it not doing anything which I fixed with [this issue](https://github.com/wix/wml/issues/48)

Answer (score 20):

I couldn't always make it work with yarn link. What i found extra useful is [yalc](https://github.com/whitecolor/yalc):

First install it globally once forever:

```
npm install -g yalc
```

In the local library/package (i'll call it `my-local-package`), and run:

```
yalc publish
```

Then in your project which uses my-local-package as a dependency, run:
(if you already have added it with any other way, first uninstall it (`npm uninstall -S my-lockal-package`)

```
yalc add my-local-package
npm install
```

If my-local-package is a native module, then run `react-native run-android` to link the dependency. (or run-ios)

If you make any change in the my-lockal-package, then:

```
cd path/of/my-local-package
yalc push //updates the local package
cd path/to/my-project
npm install
react-native run-android (or run-ios)
```

In case the update hasn't been applied, try to `cd android && ./gradlew clean && cd ..` and then rerun: `react-native run-android`.

Comment: thanks. I use `yalc` and metro config `watchFolders` to supoort link and hot reload. 

Answer (score 9):

I'm having the same issue while developing a native module wrapper around an existing native SDK. At first I followed @aayush-shrestha's suggestion to install the package locally. Like this:

```
npm install ../<package-folder> --save
```

This works as long as I reference the module via `NativeModules`. Import it:

```
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';
```

And then access a module called `ActualModuleName` like this:

```
NativeModules.ActualModuleName
```

But it fails when I attempt to import the module by name:

```
import { ActualModuleName } from 'react-native-actualmodulename'
```

To make that work I had to first pack the package. Run this in the package's root directory:

```
npm pack
```

This generates a gzipped tarball:

```
react-native-actualmodulename-1.0.0.tgz
```

Now install that in your app:

```
npm install <path/to>/react-native-actualmodulename-1.0.0.tgz
```

An enormous downside to this is that you have to re-pack the package every time you make a change to the module. The only workaround I know of is to modify the package's files in `node_modules` directly and then copy those changes back to your repo when you're done.

But the upside is that your app's source can import `ActualModuleName` the same way you'll import it once it's released via `npm`; no environment-specific code necessary.

Comment: It fail to install pod dependencies, when npm install .tgz file.

Comment: @girish_pro pod dependencies still need to be installed separately; run `pod install` in the `ios` dir before packing the extension

Comment: @wayne_burkett `pod install` not installing sub dependencies. My .tgz file depend on `react-native-branch` which need both node_module and Pod. But when I directly add  .tgz file and `pod install` in ios folder, then it not installing `react-native-branch` pod, only node_module.

Answer (score 8):

You can use npm link using Metro. Just add the source folder of the linked package to `watchFolders` in your `metro.config.js`.

Comment: this is the best answer. when you install a local package via npm install 'path/to/local/package', or in your package.json with 'file://path/to/local/package', npm links to the local package without copying. metro bundler does not know how to import these packages properly. you can update metro bundler config to do this. I cannot put much detail in comments but it's a 3 line addition to metro.config.js and you can read more details in this excellent write up (not by me): https://medium.com/@alielmajdaoui/linking-local-packages-in-react-native-the-right-way-2ac6587dcfa2

Answer (score 3):

Change your package.json

```
//...
"dependencies": {
   //...
    "my-button" : "file:../"
  },
//...
```

Comment: I tried this method already, this way will copy entire project to `example/node_modules`, not just a symlink. It's not very convenient to update dependency.

Comment: This solution would be perfect for us but we still get the same `module not found` error. Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

Ran into the same problem. While I could not make `npm link` work as it should, I worked around it by installing the local package in the project folder

```
npm install ../<package-folder> --save
```

This will install the package like a regular package but from the local folder. 
The downside is that the changes you make on the package will not be reflected. You will have to `npm install` after every change.

Comment: It doesn't work. I see the package included in `node_modules` but when I run the app, it gives error `Module 'xyz' does not exist in the Haste module map`

Comment: It might be that this command created a symlink under `node_modules` and for example React Native does not work with them. Instead, try this:
```npm install $(npm pack <folder> | tail -1)```. Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54588310

Answer (score 2):

I also came across this problem. After visiting the below link, I came to know that react- native does not support symlinks.[Click here][1]

However, I have solved this by adding these lines in the metro.config.js file. Please replace `your_module_name` with your module name.

```
const path = require('path');

const thirdPartyPath = path.resolve(__dirname + '/../your_module_name/');  // Path of your local module

const thirdParty= {
  'your_module_name': thirdPartyPath,
  };

const watchFolders = [ thirdPartyPath];

module.exports = {
// existing dependencies
resolver: {
  thirdParty,
  },
  watchFolders
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem.

I tried to install a local module using `npm`, and kept running into the issue of not being able to resolve the module, even though I could see the folder in node_modules and autocomplete of class and method names worked.

I was able to bypass it by installing the local library using `yarn` instead of `npm` after seeing this open [issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29977) on github. Issue was opened September 2020 and no comment from Facebook as of yet.

Comment: Were you able to make it work with Yarn? Unfortunately, I can't

Comment: @iRohitBhatia yes i was able to install it using Yarn. what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: Same as the OP. I will share more details on the weekend. Thanks btw :)

Answer (score 0):

This work for me:

**step 1 go to package:**

```
npm link packageNameHere
```

This will link this package to global node_module

**step 2 go to directory which you want to use this package and run these**

```
npm link pathToPackageDirectory
npm install pathToPackageDirectory
```

ex: npm link ~/myDemoPackage

This will link global node_moudle to this project

**If you want to import package to file, USE FILE PATH INSTEAD OF PACKAGE NAME !**

ex:

my package name is stripe-api-helper. my code are in src/index.ts
then I need to resolve like this:

```
import { postStripe, Item } from '@aliciaForDemo/stripe-api-helper/src'
```

if u use '@aliciaForDemo/stripe-api-helper' it will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Could never get my own environment working using any other suggestions, but found a hack that works well (though not ideal) that can be easily set up in just a few lines of code and without changing your RN project configuration.

Use `fs.watch` for changes recursively in the directory where you're working on your library, and copy the updates over whenever there's been a change:

```js
import fs from 'fs'

const srcDir = `./your-library-directory`
const destDir = `../your-destination-directory`

fs.watch("./src/", {recursive: true}, () => {
  console.log('copying...')
  fs.cp(srcDir, destDir, { overwrite: true, recursive: true }, function() {
    console.log('copied')
  })
})
```

Answer (score -3):

For those still looking for a simple solution without other dependency, try this:

```
yarn --version
1.21.1

npm --version
6.13.4
```

1. Install in project root

```
cd my-button
yarn install or npm install
```

2. register linking in my-button

```
yarn link or npm link
```

3. Install example project

```
cd example
yarn add ../ or npm add ../
```

4. link to my-button

```
yarn link my-button or npm link my-button
```

5. complete pod installation (if necessary)

```
cd ios
pod install
```

Comment: Im using for React Native just fine.. if its not working for u doesnt mean its not working at all.. thanks for the downvote.

Comment: Isn't this exactly what OP did?

Answer (score -6):

Try to run

```
npm run watch
```

inside the button package. Currently, I'm using this to apply changes from the library to my main project. Please let me know if it works!