# Install local package as dependency with react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-web

I am trying to use a package from a relative path and I have done `npm install ../../ExamplePackage` and `react-native install ../../ExamplePackage`. These packages are relative by multiple levels and not just one.

I am getting the following errors

```
error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `ExamplePackage` from `/Users/vikasagr/workspace/test/ReactNative/MyPackage/src/index.js`: Module `ExamplePackage` does not exist in the Haste module map

This might be related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968
To resolve try the following:
  1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.
  2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.
  3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.  4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`.
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (/Users/vikasagr/workspace/test/ReactNative/MyPackage/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:161:1460)
    at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (/Users/vikasagr/workspace/test/ReactNative/MyPackage/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ResolutionRequest.js:91:16)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (/Users/vikasagr/workspace/test/ReactNative/MyPackage/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:272:4579)
    at dependencies.map.relativePath (/Users/vikasagr/workspace/test/ReactNative/MyPackage/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:376:19)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at resolveDependencies (/Users/vikasagr/workspace/test/ReactNative/MyPackage/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:374:16)
    at /Users/vikasagr/workspace/test/ReactNative/MyPackage/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:212:33
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (/Users/vikasagr/workspace/test/ReactNative/MyPackage/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:297:313)
    at /Users/vikasagr/workspace/test/ReactNative/MyPackage/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:297:473
```

I tried all the steps but nothing worked. I also tried haul but that wasn't also working for me.

Comment: is the `ExamplePackage` real npm package? it has package.json of its own?

Comment: Yes. It has a package.json but its not on NPM

Comment: after you do `npm install ../../ExamplePackage` you see it added in project' package.json?

Comment: yes, I do see it in package.json

Comment: is this relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44061155/react-native-npm-link-local-dependency-unable-to-resolve-module ?

Comment: I tried haul and other things, but those don't seem to work for me.

Comment: I am working with wml and it is good

Comment: I'm also having this problem (though I'm installing with `yarn add file:../mything`).  Same error and working through the suggested steps doesn't fix it.

Answer (score 9):

Symlinks were probably causing your problem. `npm install` with a local path installs libraries in `node_modules` with a symlink pointing to the local path of the package. Unfortunately this causes an issue with the react native metro bundler (" does not exist in the Haste module map").

I had the same issue with `npm install`. `react-native install` works for me, and that does not create symlinks.

Using `wml` is another good approach. It replicates the behavior of a symlink by automatically copying changes between your local library and its installed copy in node_modules.

See https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/23327 for a similar issue.

Comment: Symlink is not copying changes, it is really a link to a disk location

Answer (score 3):

You can try WML.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/wml

What it does:

> replaces npm link with something that actually works!

It worked for me !

Cheers

Comment: To me, it log stdout when I change content of a watched file, but looking at the destination, it is still using the old file.