# TaskQueue: Error with task: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.view._component.measureInWindow') in react native

Tags: react-redux, react-native

I am very new to react native, I am facing this issue with very simple demo app while handling screen navigation 
Getting this error message
TaskQueue: Error with task: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.view._component.measureInWindow')

Here is screen shot of error :

[image]

here is my code
App.js

```html
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import HomeActivity from './components/HomeActivity';
import ProfileActivity from './components/ProfileActivity';
const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: HomeActivity,
    },
    Profile: {
      screen: ProfileActivity,
    },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
  },
);
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
    <RootStack />
    );
  }
}
```

HomeActivity.js

```html
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View, Button} from 'react-native';
class HomeActivity extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Home',
    headerStyle: {backgroundColor: '#03A9F4'},
    headerTintColor: '#fff',
    headerTitleStyle: {fontWeight: 'bold'},
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.headerText}>Home Activity</Text>
        <Button
          title="Go to Profile Activity"
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile')}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  headerText: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
});
export default HomeActivity;
```

ProfileActivity.js

```html
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button} from 'react-native';
class ProfileActivity extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Profile',
    headerStyle: {backgroundColor: '#73C6B6'},
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.headerText}>Profile Activity</Text>
        <Button
          title="Go to Home"
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')}
        />
        <Text style={styles.headerText}>Create a New Profile Screen </Text>
        <Button
          title="Go to new Profile"
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.push('Profile')}
        />
        <Text style={styles.headerText}> Go Back </Text>
        <Button
          title="Go Back"
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  headerText: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
});
export default ProfileActivity;
```

```html
 "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.7",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.1.4",
    "react": "16.11.0",
    "react-native": "0.62.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.1",
    "react-native-paper": "2.1.3",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.7.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^0.7.3",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.4.0",
    "react-navigation": "2.6.2"
  }
```

Comment: which version of react-navigation are you using?

Comment: I have the same error. I think is for the new version of react-native, and the new version of react-native-safe-area-view.

Comment: @Ilario  have added list of dependencies

Answer (score 60):

This happens becouse the react-navigate use old version of SafeView.

**You have 2 ways:**

**1.** Long way: need to migrate to v5 react-navigation [v4 to v5 migration](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/upgrading-from-4.x).

For me its  difficult and will take too much changes in my project.

**2.** Very fast and ugly solution:

Go to the dir  **YOUR_PROJECT_PATH/node_modules/react-native-safe-area-view/index.js**
and update:

**from:**

```
this.view._component.measureInWindow((winX, winY, winWidth, winHeight) => {
```

**to:**

```
this.view.getNode().measureInWindow((winX, winY, winWidth, winHeight) => {
```

You can try my fork:

`"react-navigation": "https://github.com/Snailapp/react-navigation.git#2.18.5",`

**UPDATED**

Fixed warning with deprecated currentlyFocusedField:

```
https://github.com/Snailapp/react-navigation.git#2.18.6
```

**UPDATED**

Added support iPhone MAX version:

```
https://github.com/Snailapp/react-navigation.git#2.18.7
```

Comment: RN says that getNode() is no longer neccessary. I Simply used this.view.measureInWindow((winX, winY, winWidth, winHeight) => { /..

Comment: @AzizStark Thanks. Fixed in    "react-navigation": "git://github.com/Snailapp/react-navigation.git#2.18.4",

Comment: Great work @LeonidVeremchuk, Thanks for this answer.. and more thanks to you that you created a fork.. this was really helpful..

Comment: Alternate Solution: paste in your class component static navigationOptions = { header: null };

Comment: patch-package should help to deal with the ugly solution

Answer (score 3):

I can confirm, the second option Leonid suggested works, a few notes:

- v5 has too many breaking changes
- fork worked, but makes syncing updates extremely hard
- upgraded to v3, fixed this bug for me

Comment: I upgraded from v2 to v4, and that fixed it.

Comment: @john-doe, Can you help in upgrading - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70782192/react-navigation-v2-upgrade-to-v3-issues

Answer (score 3):

For me this happened when I upgraded Expo to SDK 38. To fix this; delete the line, `"react-native-safe-area-view": "whatever version"` from your package.json file. Then run `expo install react-native-safe-area-view`. Running this command when no version of that package exists upgrades your installed package to the latest compatible (with Expo) version.

Answer (score 1):

Went for the ugly solution pointed out by Leonid :D Since npm >= 2.0.0 local dependencies are supported, so I ended up adding `react-native-safe-area-view` to my repo and added

```
"dependencies": {
  ...
  "react-native-safe-area-view": "file:./dependencies/react-native-safe-area-view",
  ...
}
```

to my `package.json`. The folder will be copied to `./node_modules` when running `npm i`

see: [Local dependency in package.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381898/local-dependency-in-package-json)

Edit:

React native does not seem to make use of symlinks, so you cant just import the local module like other modules. To make this work you need navigate to the root of the specific module and run `npm pack` to zip the module into a tarball. Then you need to run
`npm i ./path/to/tarball.tgz`
to install the local module. Now also react native should be able to reference the module.

Source: [React Native: npm link local dependency, unable to resolve module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44061155/react-native-npm-link-local-dependency-unable-to-resolve-module), Waynes answer