Node Js AWS lambda layers code to run locally
I have a code that runs  a lambda function and uses lambda layers. The code works as expected in AWS environment.
For simple lambdas i can run the lambda locally by providing the prerequisite 'env' file and running using the command
node --input-type=module -e "import {handler} from './index.js'; console.log(await handler(JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./event.json'))));";

For layers that has only simple logic and no nodemodules i tried creating a directory /opt and copied the contents of the layer over and it works as expected without any code changes.
But when I tried to run the code with lambda layers that has nodemodule references, locally it throws the error module not found
Is there a way this can be done ? Any references will be appreciated.
Thanks

I think your issue is probably broken symlinks in the node modules. There are various options to avoid symlinks dependent on your setup. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21425980/npm-install-without-symlinks-option-not-working as a starting point.

Can you run your local tests using AWS SAM CLI? That's what AWS suggests, and what I did in the past, when facing a similar issue.
# Invoking function with event file
$ sam local invoke "Ratings" -e event.json

# Invoking function with event via stdin
$ echo '{"message": "Hey, are you there?" }' | sam local invoke --event - "Ratings"

# For more options
$ sam local invoke --help

Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-cli-using-invoke.html
